# Creating a function in r to change string values

Tags: r, string, replace, dplyr

I've been trying to create a function in R that lets me change string values:

So for example I have entries "12" in my dataframe and I want to change these values to "1-2" using a function() and then applying them to my dataframe using apply()

I've tried this:

```
mistake_fix<- function() {

df$column1<-  replace(column1, "12", "1-2")


df$column1<- replace(column1, "67", "6-7")

}
```

And then to apply it to my dataframe

```
%>% apply(MARGIN =2, FUN= mistake_fix)
```

Clearly there is something wrong as r keeps telling me it cannot find object "column1"
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried `apply(df, 2, function(x) gsub("12", "1-2", x))` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `gsub`:

```r
mistake_fix <- function(x) gsub("67", "6-7", gsub("12", "1-2", x))

apply(df, 2, mistake_fix)
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver! I kept playing around with using gsub but it kept turning my dataframe into a vector, I just converted it back and it works perfectly now. Thanks again!

Comment: I have upvoted +1, as it is the more practical way of using `gsub()` avoiding conditionals like ifelse or case_when. Amazing!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `case_when` to replace multiple such values.

```
mistake_fix<- function(column1) {
  dplyr::case_when(column1 == '12' ~ '1-2', 
                   column1 == '67' ~ '6-7')
}
```

and then apply the function to all columns.

```
df[] <- lapply(df, mistake_fix)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can change the function to add an argument to the function and then use that in `apply`

```
mistake_fix<- function(x) {
     x <- replace(x, "12", "1-2")
    x <- replace(x, "67", "6-7")
   return(x)

    }

apply(df, 2, mistake_fix)
```